# Which (possibly French) sci-fi movie features a remote control that turns a basement door into a door to another world?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a French (I think) movie about a guy who found a remote control which changes a normal door in a basement to door between different worlds. It is from '80 or '70 not sure. Does someone have any idea what is the name of this movie?

Comment: That's really not a lot of detail to go with

Comment: @HorusKol: Yes, but that is all I remember. Also I remember that major part (or all) of action is going in Paris in our world. The inventor of the door lives in another world with his douther. The "guy" falls in love with her, and she wants to return to Earth with him. The "other world" is wild, without inteligent life. Maybe also without animals (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds similar to the New Twilight Zone Episode "The World Next Door" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Next_Door_(The_Twilight_Zone)), which was first broadcast on 10/18/86.

It starred Geroge Wendt (Norm from "Cheers") as an unsuccessful inventor who found a bolted door is his basaement. When he opened and passed through it, he entered the basement of a similar house in an alternate universe where gender roles were reversed and he was a successful inventor, as the alternate universe was technologically in the Victorian age and his inventions were viewed as state-of-the-art.

Comment: No, it is different. I watched a part of that episode of "The Twilight Zone" on YouTube. Also I'm sure it is full-size movie.